# cakephp 2.8 keep encrypted data in database not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp, encryption

I have to keep 2 fields(`question`,`options`) of questions table in encrypted form

core.php

```
Configure::write('Security.ekey', '1234567890~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]<>,./?qwertrpoiuytlkskhsffgzxmnxcbvLAKSJHFJPOQWUTERLKDJAD');
```

in `Question` modal i have

```
public $encryptedFields = array('question', 'options');
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {    
        foreach($this->encryptedFields as $fieldName){
            if(!empty($this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName])){
                $this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName] = Security::rijndael(
                        $this->data[$this->alias][$fieldName],
                        Configure::read('Security.ekey'), 'encrypt');
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

 public function afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
     //debug($results); this return nothing while data is being displayed having question and option fields null
    foreach($this->encryptedFields as $fieldName){
        if(!empty($results[$this->alias][$fieldName])){
            $results[$this->alias][$fieldName] = Security::rijndael(
                    $results[$this->alias][$fieldName], 
                    Configure::read('Security.ekey'), 'decrypt');
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

I have searched different blogs and stackoverflow questions
also tried changing datatype of fields to (text,blob,longblob)
length of these fields may be long (equalent to text datatype) please also suggest which datatype will be best to keep its encrypted string.

Comment: What is the value of `Configure::read('Security.ekey')`? And You should call  `parent::beforeSave();` and `parent::afterFind()` just to be safe.

Comment: I have wrote myown encrypt and decrypt functions and moved all the code to a `Behavior` it is working fine when there is no non-english char, if encrypted string contain something like `�` debug($this->data) showing nothing and in db other fields are inserted but not those which are supposed to be encrypted